# Port forwarding for accessing the computer with public IP

Tags: windows, port-forwarding

I found this manual how to set port forwarding but I am not sure how to fill my router form?

(sorry I don't know hot to upload picture directly)
https://ibb.co/NnvNfBg

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The best solution here really is to check the manual for your device for instructions on how to set these parameters. But you can try the following:

- *Name* - Type a descriptive name for the port forwarding rule.
- *Protocol* - Keep this set as `TCP`.
- *WAN Host IP Address* - Try leaving this blank initially. Otherwise, possible candidates for this field might be your router address or your Public IP. This seems to accept an IP range, but putting only a single IP should be fine. Try using the first four boxes first.
- *LAN Host* - Put the local IP (i.e. the IP of the device on your network) for whatever computer or device you wish to handle the incoming requests (ex. your server).
- *WAN Port* - Put the incoming port (i.e. from the internet) to be forwarded.
- *LAN Host Port* - This should match the WAN Port (above), unless your local computer or device processing the incoming requests is using a different port for a given service. Again, this seems to accept a port range, but try using the first box first.